# For security reasons, a Popup cannot be hidden by the edge of a screen

Tags: c#, wpf, security

Taken from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#When

In regards to the popup controls that appear in WPF applications.

Just this phrase confuses me:
"For security reasons, a Popup cannot be hidden by the edge of a screen."

Any ideas of why/what security purposes that might be?

Comment: Wild guess: If you have a 2 screen display, with one of the display being on a projector and the other being on your laptop, you may not want a popup from your screen to show on the projector?

Comment: Yea, fair enough, I understand the usability issues of having popups appear anywhere, but I was wondering specifically what the *security* issues are

Comment: With an "invisible" popup you could try to sneaky steal the focus, and get the user to enter passwords into your program?

Comment: Well, having information shown to a roomful of people when you do not intend to could be seen as a security issue, couldn'it?

Comment: That's true, but then the security issue might be the user, rather than the program ;)

Comment: @Ellimist0, if a program displays someone's private information due to bad usability, then it is a program security issue. It's not a matter of users being bad at computers, more about making software easily usable without users having to be worried about putting themselves at risk. Security isn't all about code exploits, it's also about reducing the risk of being able to take advantage of users.

Comment: I agree, and that would make sense, but it still doesn't explain why you can make an entire canvas or panel hidden, or invisible but still usable which can exploit a user, and this is NOT a security risk. 

However placing a popup off screen is a security risk

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion would be so you can't hide options or text off of the display, tricking users into thinking there is only one option when multiple may exist.

If a popup doesn't allow input to the program until a response has been provided, but the popup is hidden off of the screen, a user may not know the popup is hidden and think the program has locked up and become unresponsive.

It's not a security hole in the sense of it being a software exploit, but it causes confusion. Once you confuse a user, it can be easier to trick them into doing something harmful to their computer since they want to fix the problem. The user may not have an understanding of how to do so and more willing to follow steps they don't understand, which can be exploited.

In general popups are meant to inform users or ask them for necessary input, and having that hidden would be poor practice since it makes the task more difficult for the user.

Comment: That seems reasonable... except you can do that without using popups. You can hide input fields, capture anything, mislead the user.
Any program running full screen made to look like windows can trick the user into doing things they don't want to.

But it does make me wonder if it's not actually a software exploit

Comment: You can do that without popups, but what if you get the popup metadata from a web service, such as position and content. If that content were to be maliciously injected, or modified, then you could take advantage of it. It's just more about removing a potential side channel attack since there is no real good use for having a popup off-screen.